# Java how to call paint in actionperform

Tags: java, action, call, paint

am try to call paint in action perform but it not work

```
btnNewButton_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

                public void paint(Graphics g) {
                    g.drawLine(10,20,50,60);
                }
            }


            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
            window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
            window.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
```

problem is it show only frame but rectangle doesn't draw

how can i edit this code help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421150/java-using-graphics-component-within-an-actionlistener

Answer (score 0):

First you should implement the paint() method on your class and then it is recall as simple function call use repaint() method on ActionListener.