# Swing paintComponent processing

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Currently I have a `JPanel` with its `paintComponent` overridden with lots of image processing based on various states. When an event occurs (infrequent) many of the states change and the images that are drawn change. It doesn't seem the best way to keep doing all the processing every time the `paintComponent` is it possible to do something like when an event occurs draw everything to a `Graphics2D` instance and then merge this with the `paintComponent` one? Is this also the best way to do it?

Comment: Paint it to a `BufferedImage`, then paint the `BufferedImage` within the `paintComponent` method

Comment: Some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21266240/2891664).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MadProgrammer suggested, storing rendered output can help you.

When the event that might change the image occurs, you can draw stuff to a `BufferedImage` like following.

```
private BufferedImage renderedImage;

public void triggerEvent(int width, int height) {
    this.renderedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = this.renderedImage.createGraphics();

    // Paint things on g.
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(this.renderedImage, 0, 0, this);
}
```

Hope this helps.