# Java graphics being drawn on top of existing graphic

Tags: java, image, graphics

Main class:

```
    public Main() {
    Frame f = new Frame();
    final Panel p = f.p;

    final Player player = new Player();

    Timer t = new Timer(UPDATE_PERIOD, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Graphics g = p.getGraphics();
            p.render(g);

            player.tick();
            player.render(g);

            g.dispose();
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Player render method:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(Images.get("player"), x, y, null);
}
```

The problem is, that all previous drawn images are still there. Example (when I change the drawn image's x or y):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You need to clear the previous draw before drawing again: `g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());`

Comment: You will need to update the question with a more [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want answers which are not guessing. Right now we don't really understand what your code is doing. (What does `p.getGraphics()` do? What are you painting to?)

Comment: @Radiodef p is the class which extends JPanel. .getGraphics() is from the superclass. 
And it will be a small game I just begun and were trying around

Comment: Well then you have received answers. (Don't paint that way.) You should also look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30175751 which demonstrates a more proper way to do painting for a game and has links to other examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw in `Swing`, you should not be getting the `Graphics` object directly from the JPanel. Instead, override the `paintComponent` method and use the parameter Graphics object to perform your custom drawing, with a call to the parent method to erase previous painting

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //custom painting goes here
}
```

If you wish to trigger a repaint, use the method by that name on the JPanel:

```
p.repaint();
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing custom rendering your your timer, you should really be doing all your painting in your paintComponent method. Something like:

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
        player.tick();
        p.repaint();
    }
```

And then re-render the player and the background in paintComponent()

Painting like you currently are runs into issues when you resize the panel, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try calling 'p.repaint()' in your ActionListener once you have changed the position of the Graphic.