# Repaint method is called but paintComponent doesn't run

Tags: java, jpanel, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm trying to make a game and make the text appear one character at a time like in most RPG games. I call repaint() near the bottom of a for loop but it runs until the last iteration through the for loop. Here is the entire class. I am using the displayMessage method. Please help.
Thank you.

```
    private class BattleTextArea extends JPanel{

    private String atk1;
    private String atk2;
    private String atk3;
    private String atk4;

    private String messageWords;

    private boolean messageDisplayed;
    private boolean finishedMessage;
    private int xSpot;
    private String charAt;

    public BattleTextArea(){

        setAtk1("1");
        setAtk2("2");
        setAtk3("3");
        setAtk4("4");

    }


    public void updateText(Pokemon poke){

        setAtk1(poke.attacks.get(0).getName());
        setAtk2(poke.attacks.get(1).getName());
        setAtk3(poke.attacks.get(2).getName());
        setAtk4(poke.attacks.get(3).getName());

        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        System.out.println("begining of paint");



        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 225);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 489, 94, 10, 10);

        if(!isMessageDisplayed()){



            if(!isAttacksSelected()){

                g.drawString("Fight", 325, 30);
                g.drawString("Bag", 425, 30);
                g.drawString("Party", 325, 75);
                g.drawString("Run", 425, 75);


            }else{

                g.drawString(getAtk1() , 50, 30);
                g.drawString(getAtk2(), 150, 30);
                g.drawString(getAtk3(), 50, 75);
                g.drawString(getAtk4(), 150, 75);
            }



            if(getSelectedButton() == 1){

                g.drawRect(320, 15, 42, 22);


            }else if(getSelectedButton() == 2){

                g.drawRect(418, 15, 42, 22);

            }else if(getSelectedButton() == 3){

                g.drawRect(320, 60, 42, 22);

            }else if(getSelectedButton() == 4){

                g.drawRect(418, 60, 42, 22);

            }


            if(getSelectedButton() == 11){

                g.drawRect(45, 15, 50, 22);


            }else if(getSelectedButton() == 12){

                g.drawRect(145, 15, 50, 22);

            }else if(getSelectedButton() == 13){

                g.drawRect(45, 60, 50, 22);

            }else if(getSelectedButton() == 14){

                g.drawRect(145, 60, 50, 22);


            }


        }else{

            //Display message


            /*int x = 20; 
            g.drawString(getMessageWords().substring(0, 1), 20,20);
            for (int i = 1; i <= getMessageWords().length(); i++) {


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);//1000 milliseconds is one second.
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }


                System.out.println("in for");
                JComponent c = bta;
                FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(c.getFont()); // or another font\

                if(i != getMessageWords().length())
                    x += fm.stringWidth(getMessageWords().substring(i, i + 1));
                else
                    x += fm.stringWidth(getMessageWords().substring(i));

                if(i != getMessageWords().length())
                    g.drawString(getMessageWords().substring(i, i + 1), x,20);
                else
                    g.drawString(getMessageWords().substring(i), x, 20);

            }//for*/

            //setFinishedMessage(true);

            System.out.println("in paint");

            System.out.println(getCharAt());
            //System.out.println(getMessageWords().length());



            g.drawString(getCharAt(), getXSpot(), 20);
            System.out.println("in if");

        }
    }//paint comp



    public void displayMessage(String message){

        //setMessageWords(message);
        setMessageDisplayed(true);


        JComponent c = bta;
        FontMetrics fm = c.getFontMetrics(c.getFont());

        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){



            setCharAt(message.substring(i, i + 1));

            System.out.println("before if");


            System.out.println(fm.stringWidth(getCharAt()));

            System.out.println(getXSpot());

            setXSpot(getXSpot() + fm.stringWidth(getCharAt()));


            System.out.println(getXSpot());


            System.out.println("right before paint");
            repaint();
            System.out.println("right after paint");


            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);//1000 milliseconds is one second.
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }//for

        setFinishedMessage(true);
    }
    public String getAtk1() {
        return atk1;
    }


    public void setAtk1(String atk1) {
        this.atk1 = atk1;
    }


    public String getAtk2() {
        return atk2;
    }


    public void setAtk2(String atk2) {
        this.atk2 = atk2;
    }


    public String getAtk3() {
        return atk3;
    }


    public void setAtk3(String atk3) {
        this.atk3 = atk3;
    }


    public String getAtk4() {
        return atk4;
    }


    public void setAtk4(String atk4) {
        this.atk4 = atk4;
    }



    public boolean isMessageDisplayed() {
        return messageDisplayed;
    }



    public void setMessageDisplayed(boolean messageDisplayed) {
        this.messageDisplayed = messageDisplayed;
    }



    public String getMessageWords() {
        return messageWords;
    }



    public void setMessageWords(String messageWords) {
        this.messageWords = messageWords;
    }


    public boolean isFinishedMessage() {
        return finishedMessage;
    }


    public void setFinishedMessage(boolean finishedMessage) {
        this.finishedMessage = finishedMessage;
    }


    public int getXSpot() {
        return xSpot;
    }


    public void setXSpot(int x) {
        this.xSpot = x;
    }


    public String getCharAt() {
        return charAt;
    }


    public void setCharAt(String charAt) {
        this.charAt = charAt;
    }
}//bta class
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745778/java-game-loop-painting-freezes-my-window/29837148#29837148. You shouldn't put `Thread.sleep` inside `paintComponent` (or anywhere on the UI thread for that matter), it freezes the UI. Use a timer instead.

Comment: @Radiodef Okay thanks, so Timer and have it call repaint and change the character being drawn in actionPreformed? I commented put the Thread.sleep in the paint and it was only in the displayMessage method. I'n not sure if that confused you.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Another example of animation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30175751 with more links as well.